# Problemas con el tamaño de la imagen en Docker

Tags: docker, importación, exportar

Tengo un problema con Docker y después de llevarme días buscando soluciones no he encontrado nada.

Os explico mi caso, tengo un proyecto en nodejs + express + angular, y un Dockerfile, cuando en mi MAC genero la imagen y la exporto para llevarmela a un NAS Sysnology el tamaño es X y la importación y ejecución es correcta, pero si hago lo mismo en otras máquinas, el tamaño es muy diferente (mas grande) y para colmo cuando lo importo en el servidor Docker del NAS me da un error y no lo importa.

¿Que puede estar pasando o haciendo mal, para que en otras máquinas no me "genere correctamente la imagen"?

Mi Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.14.2

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0):

¿Ha contemplado subirlo a docker hub? Puede crear una cuenta y subir sus imágenes sin problema de forma gratuita, podría ser una opción.

Si le suena la opción le debe colocar un tag a su imagen, por ejemplo, si su imagen se llama `mi-imagen` (en su máquina local) y tiene el hash `daee8d81dafc` y su cuenta de usuario es `armandito`, lo puede hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
docker tag daee8d81dafc armandito/mi-imagen:latest
```

Luego, se logea en dockerhub (puede hayar mucha documentación al respecto):

```
docker login
```

La sube a docker hub:

```
docker push armandito/mi-imagen:latest
```

luego la descarga donde necesite:

```
docker pull armandito/mi-imagen:latest
```